# Using word embeddings in text classifier

Tags: classification, word-embeddings

I have a bunch of sentences that I want to do binary classification with SVM.

My sentences have varying lengths form 4 to 34. If I use word embeddings such as word2vec or skip gram to convert my words into word vectors, I would end up with matrices of very different sizes due to differences in sentence length.

What is the best way to get around that? I know that if I were to use a neural network classifier, I would just pad with zeroes and let the neural network figure out the features. But If I were to use a classical machine learning classification method, what is the best way to deal with sentences of varying lengths?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked doc2vec? Doc2vec returns a fixed representation for each document (sentence in your case), regardless of its length. [Here](https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf) is the original paper. There is also a Python implementation from the [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) package.

Another usual approach for text classification is to calculate the tf-idf matrix and use it as input to a classifier, in which case the columns of the matrix are the features. The tf-idf matrix represents the sentences in its rows and the unique terms (words) of all your sentences in its columns. Each element in the matrix is the tf-idf value of this sentence-term. You can find more information in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) page. scikit-learn has an implementation of tf-idf [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have already tried Doc2Vec but the accuracy I get is not satisfactory. This is why I am trying other word embedding solutions.

tf.idf would be a count based approach. I want to try embeddings

Answer (score 0):

For inputs of varying lengths I suggest to use an encoder/decoder architecture, such as an LSTM model. You can use pretrained encoders for example from the flair library https://github.com/zalandoresearch/flair .

Essentially you would be giving the model a sequence of words as input and it will generate a context vector (essentially the hidden layer of the LSTM). you can then use the context vector as input to a normal fully connected hidden layer and a softmax to do your classification. That's the theoretical setup. Whether that works or not remains to be explored :)